# Use C dll in windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, dll, windows-phone-7

A simple but fundamental question :

Is it possible to use a dll devlopped in C, in my WP7 project ?

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible unless your app is being bundled with the device manufacturer or network operator. I believe they get to use native code, but for everyone else it's Silverlight or XNA.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible, as long as you can activate the COM Bridge and be able to register the DLL with the OS. This is not a well-documented capability and it will pretty much get the application rejected from the Marketplace (since it is not one of the officially supported features), but you can certainly do it "just for fun".

Here is what Chris Walshie has to say about it:

http://blog.walshie.me/2010/11/12/windows-phone-7-native-apps-the-missing-link

Yes, it will involve a lot more work, but it was already found that a lot of OEMs are bundling their applications with native DLLs, and that pattern can be successfully used in third-party applications as well (looking at what XDA guys do).

Comment: Have you actually gotten that to work?  I failed to get this to work.  It describes how to register a DLL but doesn't exactly explain how you call methods exposed by the DLL.

Comment: Not yet. But: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1006331 Also there is much more.