# Calling C++ DLL in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c++, windows-phone-7, dll

All, I have seen the following two questions on this topic

[import c++ dll to windows phone project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730774/import-c-dll-to-windows-phone-project)

[Use C dll in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019922/use-c-dll-in-windows-phone-7)

but they are both over a year old. Are the following

1. P/Invoke from user code is not supported.
2. C++/CLI is not supported either.

statments still true? Is there any other way to call a C++ DLL from a WP7 application at this time.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah the Statement is still true, you cannot use either of them. Just Managed SL-Code is allowed .

Comment: +1 Is there any other way around this restriction to facilitate the callin of C++ DLLs. We have a huge C++ code base... Thanks for your time.

Comment: Here are some very interesting Ideas for porting the Code:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2455372/944779
So with this you could be able(big maybe) port your codebase to c++/SLI and then use it for a SL-Projekt which then is partly compatible with WP7.